# Python script error with numbers 01

Tags: python

I have the following script and there seems to be an error:

```
import random, time
from random import randint

while True:
    part_1 = randint(1,31)
    part_2 = randint(1,12)
    part_3 = random.choice([81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,00,01,02,03,04])

    if part_3 == 01 or part_3 == 1:
        part_3 = 0 + part_3
    full = str(part_1) + " " + str(part_2) + " " + str(part_3)
    print full
    time.sleep(1)
```

In part_3 I want to make it so it's 01, but it just prints off as 1. I want the same behavior with with 2, 3, etc.  How would I do this?

Comment: Please edit your post to include your source code directly in the question.  External links may not last forever, and future users will be unable to read and understand your question without the code.

Answer (score 2):

Change your declaration of `full` to:

```
full = "%02d %02d %02d" % (part_1, part_2, part_3)
```

You can read more about format strings [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: @Ted6794 Don't cast your integers to strings; just leave them as integers in the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer using [`str.format`](https://pyformat.info/)

```
part_1 = randint(1,31)
part_2 = randint(1,12)
part_3 = random.choice([81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,00,01,02,03,04])

full = ('{:02d} '*3).format(part_1, part_2, part_3).rstrip() 
# '16 09 97'
```